# How to find the right usb wifi adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, adapter

Please,can someone suggest to me which can be the right usb wifi adapter,I have Acer Aspire One AOA150/ZG5 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.It works with wireless "g",I'd like to improve my connection speed passing to wireless "n"or "ac"at 2,4 Ghz.But I have to find a right adapter,with the right driver and kernel.Probably I need to know how to find right driver and how to update the kernel version,because I'm a beginner.Can someone help me.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with the NETIS WF2120.  It's dirt cheap($4-9 USD), small form factor, and plays well with Ubuntu/Debian without any tweaks.  Newegg seems to run the best discount, usually with some sort of mail-in rebate, though Amazon sells them as well.  I've purchased about 6 of them so far and can't say enough positive things.